# How to manually specify the search language in Startpage.com?

Tags: search-engine, startpage

[Google does not allow easily changing the search language](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/16/how-to-get-google-search-results-for-a-different-language/). A metasearch engine [Searx](https://github.com/asciimoo/searx) (the official instance functions poorly) supports switching by using [language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) (such as `:de` and `:es`). I constantly toggle between my native language and English, but Google gives atrocious results from both English to Finnish and Finnish to English. Startpage's search language can be set [in the settings](https://www.startpage.com/search/settings), but is too inconvenient for sustained use.

Comment: can you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: @user0: I mean specifying the language in the search query, for instance `:fi Helsinki` instead of going to the Startpage settings each time or using the en-US results.

Comment: I wasn't aware at the time of asking that Startpage mixes results from Google regions — my experience was entirely based on the unfiltered Google results. Startpage's method seems very good, but I still sometimes only want results from one region.

Answer (score 1):

- the easiest way is to change it directly in URL before the search

  ```
  startpage.com/en
  ```




  ```
  startpage.com/fi
  ```




  ```
  startpage.com/es
  ```

  [image]

  [image: 0]

---

- then you can bookmark it (both) and click on one which you want to summon